# Dual of a Symmetric Design

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-designs

I'm struggling with the following problem regarding designs:

Let *D* be a $(v,k,\lambda)$ symmetric design with point set $\Omega$ and set of block $\mathcal{B}$. That is $|\mathcal{B}|=v$.

The **dual** of *D* is $D^*$, the design with point set $\mathcal{B}$ and set of blocks $\Omega$ where a “point” *B* of $D^*$ is in the “block” *x* of $D^*$ if and only if the point *x* of *D* lies in the block *B* of *D*.  Prove that $D^*$ is a $(v,k,\lambda)$-design.

What I thought to do was the following:

For $B\in\mathcal{B}$  and $x\in\Omega$ we have $B\in x \iff x\in B$ where LHS is in $D^*$ and RHS is in *D*.

Let every $x\in\Omega$ be in *r* blocks in $\mathcal{B}$. Since $v=b$, where *b* is $|\mathcal{B}|$ we have $r=k$. Now exactly *k* blocks will go to *x* when forming $D^*$ and therefore $|x|=k$ $\forall{x\in\Omega}$. So then $D^*$ is a $(v,k,\mu)$-design.

Let's assume that $\mu\neq\lambda$. Since $D^*$ is a design, we have $\mu(v-1)=r(k-1)=k^2-k$. But since *D* is a design we have $\lambda(v-1)=k^2-k$ and so it must be that $\mu = \lambda$. So each pair of "points" in $D^*$ appears in exactly $\lambda$ "blocks".

Hence $D^*$ is a $(v,k,\lambda)$-design.

Is this a sufficient proof or should I try another approach?

Comment: You are just using the fact that in a symmetric design, $v=b$, $k=r$, and that any two blocks share precisely $\lambda$ common varieties. This last part is usually stated as a theorem. If you are proving this on your own, you can't just assume that $D^{*}$ is a $(v,k,\mu)$ design. The crucial step to this exercise is proving that $D^{*}$ is a design at all.

Comment: (i.e. your "So then $D^{*}$ is a $(v,k,\mu)$-design" statement needs a lot more justification)